# Is it possible to "drill down" into objects with jql REST queries

Tags: jira

Let's say I need to get the list of all Jira issues updated in the last week but I really only care about each issue's summary and project id fields. When I do

```
/rest/api/2/search?jql=updated%3E=-1w&fields=key&fields=summary,project
```

I get back json with a whole object for the project including link to avatars at different resolutions

```
{
    "expand":"schema,names",
    "startAt":0,
    "maxResults":1000,
    "total":1726,
    "issues":[
        {
        "expand":"operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,transitions,renderedFields",
        "id":"24976",
        "self":".../rest/api/2/issue/24976",
        "key":"ABC-241",
        "fields":{
            "summary":"As a client, blah blah blah",
            "project":{
              "self":.../rest/api/2/project/10732",
              "id":"10732",
              "key":"ABC",
              "name":"Ay Bee See",
              "avatarUrls":{
                "48x48":".../secure/projectavatar?pid=10732&avatarId=11046",
                "24x24":".../secure/projectavatar?size=small&pid=10732&avatarId=11046",
                "16x16":".../secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&pid=10732&avatarId=11046",
                "32x32":".../secure/projectavatar?size=medium&pid=10732&avatarId=11046"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        ...
```

This makes the responses much larger than I need them to be. Is there some way to form the query to not return all that project info, and *just* return its id?

Comment: @JAL I'm curious why you edited out jira-api, this is specifically about the API (a projection doesn't even make sense in the UI) and that's the correct way of denoting it, isn't it?

Comment: I edited out the tag because I was going through the new tags and cleaning up ones that I felt were duplicates.  The [tag:jira] tag appears to cover API access (at least according to the [tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jira/info)).  Feel free to re-add it if you feel that it adds value to your question.

Comment: Nah, we're good

Comment: Just wanted to add something:
for most of JIRA functionality, a Project's ID and Key are practically interchangeable so you can get a list of the Issues that match your JQL without the `project` variable and then extract the Project Key from the Issue Key and you will end up with a list of all Projects.

Comment: yeah...but project keys can be changed ...

Comment: Doesn't matter unless you're trying to cache something.

Comment: @rorschach indeed - for sync-ing that is in fact the case

Comment: @GeorgeMauer in that case you're best off with just expanding `project` and dealing with the extra (albeit really small) load when querying.  

One more follow-up question. Are you periodically running whatever application you have that does the JQL query or do you have a server that's running 24/7?

Comment: @rorschach I'm registering webhooks if that's what you're getting at, but sometimes the server is going to bounce and you just got to do a full reconciliation.

Comment: Yeah, I had webhooks in mind but I agree that they're not a fool-proof solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not, the fields you see in the expanded `project` variable are the bare minimum JIRA returns.